# Como validar retorno de uma método como array de objetos php7?

Tags: php-7

Então, consegui criar uma **classe** com um **método** para **verificar** se o **retorno** de uma outra **função** é um **booleano**:

**Tecnicamente** e aí entraria a **orientação** de vocês, funciona assim:

```
class Classe {}

$a = new Classe();

$util = new Util();

echo $util->instancia ("Classe", $a) ? "Confirmado!" : "Não é uma instancia dessa classe!";
```

Mas não estou conseguindo **adaptar** isso em:

```
public function buscarTodos () : array ::{}
```

Preciso conseguir **garantir** que o **retorno** da função `buscarTodos` seja de fato um **array** de **objetos** de uma dada **classe**.

No **java**, basta fazer:

```
public function buscarTodos () : array<Pessoas> {}
```

Por exemplo que já está resolvida a parte que preciso resolver.
Mas no **php** está muito **difícil** conseguir esse **resultado**.

Obs.: Eu poderia **garantir** isso no **corpo** do **método**. Mas não é esse o **objetivo**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP, diferente do Java, possui tipagem dinâmica. Uma variável que agora é *string* pode receber um inteiro e mudar seu tipo sem problemas e isso, inclusive, é esperado da linguagem. Isso é possível porque uma variável do PHP é construída com base em uma estrutura mais complexa do C que armazena tanto o valor atual quando uma referência ao tipo.

Dito isso, para a linguagem, quando você cria um *array*, não importa se é um *array* de números, de *strings* ou de instâncias variadas. *Array* é *array*. Somente com a declaração de retorno você não conseguirá garantir que seja um *array* apenas de um tipo. Fazer isso não faz sentido no PHP e se precisa isso na sua aplicação talvez o PHP seja a linguagem errada.

Para garantir que todos os elementos do *array* sejam todas instâncias de uma determinada classe, você necessariamente precisará percorrer o *array* e verificar um a um com o `instanceof`.

Existe ferramentas de terceiros em que você poderá utilizar a anotação de retorno pelos comentários:

```
/**
 * @return Classe[]
 */
```

Mas isso não é da linguagem em si. Inclusive essa sintaxe já foi proposta em 2014 e foi recusado:

- [PHP RFC: Array Of](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrayof)

Comment: puxa vida! Recusaram é?

Comment: Sim, porque não faz sentido ter declaração de retorno em uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica.

Comment: Bom eu penso que deveria ter a opção disponível para quem quisesse usar mesmo assim. Embora realmente não faça sentido para esse tipo de linguagem mas seria interessante  fornecer esse recurso caso alguém precisasse dele. Nesse caso, o programador iria arranjar os recursos de que precisa. Mas está ótimo assim. É tocar pra frente. Obrigado por enquanto! Quem sabe alguém da comunidade  já teve alguma ideia parecida e encontro solução.

Comment: Essa é a questão: você usa uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica se isso te dá alguma vantagem. Se é a tipagem estática que traz benefícios, basta usar outra linguagem.

Comment: Basicamente você não compra uma chave de fenda esperando que ela tenha uma serra para caso você precise cortar algo.

Comment: entendi agora. obrigafo

Answer (score -1):

Talvez ::class pode te ajudar, pois nos testes aqui ele confirmou o tipo da classe.

Eu testo da seguinte forma (Mais importante está no fim):

```
<?php
namespace classes\util;

class Util {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function instancia($classe, $objeto): bool {
        return $objeto instanceof $classe;
    }

}

class Classe {

}

$a = new Classe();

$util = new Util();

// Ao invés de uma string, passe de fato a referência ao tipo da classe. Repare no método abaixo
echo $util->instancia(Classe::class, $a) ? "Confirmado!" : "Não é uma instancia dessa classe!";
?>
```

Comment: `Classe::class` é só um açúcar sintático que retorna `"Classe"`, mas com o *namespace* resolvido. Neste exemplo, não fez diferença, então a resposta, em si, não teve um fundamento e isso não está relacionado com o problema em questão que é definir o retorno como um *array* de instâncias.